# How to rename a git commit in Terminal

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, terminal

I've used `git commit --amend` to rename a git commit. After struggling how to even write anything (I'm using Terminal or Terminal in Visual Studio Code) I think I accidentally discovered that pressing `a` allows you to write.

I now have the name I want to save the commit as ('css reset'). I literally just do not know how what to do next. Why aren't there instructions?

[image]

Comment: Yep that worked hadn't used that `:wq` command in a while. Going to write down this method as a potential technique for future editing

Answer (score 2):

It's probably opening the commit message in `vi`.  Use ESC to return to Normal mode, then use `:wq` to save and quit.

You can change what editor git uses with [`git config --global core.editor <new editor>`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_core_editor).

Comment: Alternatively learn just enough `vi` to get by. It isn't that hard, and in fact it's kind of fun once you get the hang of it. :)